# How can I get the title from the strings file when implementing favorites?

Tags: sonos

I am trying to add favorites by following [this instruction](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-favorites/), but I cannot get the title to be read from the strings file. What am I doing wrong?

This is my `getExtendedMetadata` response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getExtendedMetadataResponse>
      <ns1:getExtendedMetadataResult>
        <ns1:mediaMetadata>
          <ns1:id>album_track:17079|193549</ns1:id>
          <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
          <ns1:title>Sabo &amp; Zeb - Sambafrica</ns1:title>
          <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
          <ns1:trackMetadata>
            <ns1:artistId>artist:1</ns1:artistId>
            <ns1:artist>Various Artists</ns1:artist>
            <ns1:albumArtistId>artist:1</ns1:albumArtistId>
            <ns1:albumArtist>Various Artists</ns1:albumArtist>
            <ns1:albumId>album:17079</ns1:albumId>
            <ns1:album>10 Years of SOL</ns1:album>
            <ns1:duration>451</ns1:duration>
            <ns1:albumArtURI>https://assets.s3.amazonaws.com/cover/30929/10.png</ns1:albumArtURI>
          </ns1:trackMetadata>
        </ns1:mediaMetadata>
        <ns1:relatedActions>
          <ns1:action>
            <ns1:id>add_track_to_my_library</ns1:id>
            <ns1:title>ADD_ITEM</ns1:title>
            <ns1:actionType>simpleHttpRequest</ns1:actionType>
            <ns1:simpleHttpRequestAction>
              <ns1:url>https://sonosdev.newmediasquad.com/v1/favorites/add/track/17079</ns1:url>
              <ns1:method>POST</ns1:method>
            </ns1:simpleHttpRequestAction>
          </ns1:action>
        </ns1:relatedActions>
      </ns1:getExtendedMetadataResult>
    </ns1:getExtendedMetadataResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is my strings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stringtables xmlns="http://sonos.com/sonosapi">
  <stringtable rev="20040502" xml:lang="en-US">
    <string stringId="ServicePromo">Welcome to YogiTunes!</string>
    <string stringId="LOGIN">Login</string>
    <string stringId="SIGNUP">Sign up</string>
    <string stringId="ADD_ITEM">Add to My Library</string>
    <string stringId="REMOVE_ITEM">Remove from My Library</string>
    <string stringId="ADD_SUCCESS">Added successfully</string>
    <string stringId="ADD_FAILED">Something went wrong. Please try again or contact us at support@yogi-tunes.com.</string>
    <string stringId="REMOVE_SUCCESS">Removed successfully</string>
    <string stringId="REMOVE_FAILED">Something went wrong. Please try again or contact us at support@yogi-tunes.com.</string>
    <string stringId="Error5Message">Retry token request.</string>
    <string stringId="Error100Message">Namaste!! Have some obstacles that need removing? Gan Gan Ganapataye! Contact us at support@yogi-tunes.com and we will get back to you as soon as possible.</string>
  </stringtable>

  [snip other languages]

</stringtables>
```

(full string file [here](https://sonosdev.newmediasquad.com/static/strings-20040601.xml))

But, this is what I see in the app:

[image]

Other strings *are* loaded correctly from the strings file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in how the Sonos app displays string text for the `<title>` entry in an `<action>` under `<relatedActions>`. This works for `<relatedBrowse>` and `<relatedText>`, which is why you're seeing it behave as expected for those actions. We have this in our backlog. I'll update this answer once it has been fixed.

Additionally, we recommend you use a `PUT` request for favoriting. Your example shows a `POST` request.

Update June 15, 2020 5:00 PM: This has been fixed in the [11.1 release](https://support.sonos.com/s/article/352). This will also be reflected in the [Sonos developer portal blog](https://developer.sonos.com/blog/) later this week.

Comment: Thank you. So, for now, I could just do `<ns1:title>Add to My Library</ns1:title>`? The app is in English only anyway.

Comment: I think you'd have to use `<ns1:title>Add_to_My_Library</ns1:title>` as this resolves to a string in the strings.xml file and the bug prevents this from happening.

Comment: While the bug has not been fixed and I am unable lookup the string from the strings file, I want to show users the correct text without underscores. That's why I was thinking about using `<ns1:title>Add to My Library</ns1:title>`.

Wouldn't `<ns1:title>Add_to_My_Library</ns1:title>` still show underscores to the user?

Comment: I don't think the title value will work with spaces. You can try it and see. That's why I suggested the underscores. It's not the best experience, but it gets the point across.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `<ns1:title>Add to My Library</ns1:title>` and it worked.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add that to the release notes. I'll update the above once this has been fixed.